# Node.js get image DPI info

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, image-processing

So I'm trying to get DPI info of a image using node.js / javascript
Using npm i tried moduels for image info, but none of them returns the DPI value.

How can I find the dpi value using nodejs / javascript

Comment: Dpi is normally only relevant if you are printing an image. Are you sure you need it and don’t just want the size in pixels?

Comment: yeah, i need to analyze and sort images for printing

Comment: Still. A 2000x2000 pixel 300dpi image and a 2000 x 2000 72dpi image are exactly the same. It’s just an exit tag.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes, I know that this setting doesn't change anything, but when you look in this picture on info details you see 72DPI and customers ask always again about this settings...